# Overriding styles of email templates for Sitecore Exm

Tags: experience-editor, exm

I need to use Sitecore email templates after overriding its styles to be of different theme colors. There is a place holder named `styles override` that is not accepting any renderings

[image: override styles place holder]

Also, I find this link on the Sitecore that doesn't match my request it requires creating a new custom template while I need to use the Sitecore templates with some modifications over styles

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/exm/90/email-experience-manager/en/walkthrough--building-a-custom-message-template.html#UUID-4b189de6-8c92-1ae2-950e-8d6af259d1c3_N1529485820703

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `styles-override` placeholder is missing the [placeholder settings](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/maximizing_usability/posts/the-power-of-placeholder-settings).

You can consider the email template like a usual Sitecore page with a presentation.
To change the CSS, you could edit `Main Layout.aspx` (which will change the styles for all the items that are using this layout) or create a control that renders a CSS tag and put it on the page.